# Get one column value from last record in mongo-db

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to fetch just one column value from last record in mongodb.

Suppose my collection name is : test

using this query to fetch the last record :

```
 db.test.find({}).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(1)
```

documents are :

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5f7c540b5e707b3df75bb844"), "date" : "2020-10-06", "time" : "16:55:00.216298"}
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5f7c542e5e707b3df75bb849"), "date" : "2020-10-06", "time" : "16:55:35.423938"}
```

Above query will give me last record.
Now I want to get the date value from last record. I know one way :

```
  db.test.find({},{'date':1}).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(1)
```

But suppose I don't know the date index then what should be the query? May be if you can provide the answer in python.

Comment: what do you mean by "date index"? you don't use "index" to project the result. you have to use the "field name". if you don't know the name of the field that you want, then you can't project the result.

Answer (score 0):

To have the desired result you can use the aggregation:

```
db.test.aggregate([{'$sort': {'_id': 1}},
                   {'$limit': 1},
                   {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'time': 0, 'date': 1}}])
```